# Why does this openMP loop not return the correct computation?

Tags: c, openmp

My code aims at combining two arrays into a third one, and doing this multiple times. I'd like to parallelize it using the means of openMP, but the result is not what I expect it to be. Namely, already the very first check breaks at a[0]!=0.

The MWE is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    long length = 10000;
    long nSamples = 1000;
    double *a, *b, *c;
    double start = 0;
    double end = 0;
    int nthreads = 0;

// Array Allocation and Initialisation
    a = (double *)malloc(length * sizeof(double));
    b = (double *)malloc(length * sizeof(double));
    c = (double *)malloc(length * sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0.0;
        b[i] = 0.0;
        c[i] = 0.0;
    }

//  Get the maximum number of threads and evaluate the number of threads per group
#pragma omp parallel shared(nthreads)
    {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads() / 2;
    }

#pragma omp parallel for shared(nthreads, a, b, c) num_threads(nthreads) collapse(2)
    for (i = 0; i < nSamples; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            a[j] = a[j] + 2.0;
            b[j] = b[j] + 2.0;
            c[j] = a[j] + b[j];
        }
    }

    /*Check correctness*/
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != 2.0 * nSamples)
        {
            printf("a not equal at %d\n", i);
            break;
        }
        if (b[i] != 2.0 * nSamples)
        {
            printf("b ot equal at %d\n", i);
            break;
        }
        if (c[i] != 4.0 * nSamples)
        {
            printf("c ot equal at %d\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

If I only parallelize the inner loop, the check works fine. To achieve this, I use:

```
    for (i = 0; i < nSamples; i++)
    {
#pragma omp parallel for private(j) shared(a, b, c) num_threads(nthreads)
        for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            a[j] = a[j] + 2.0;
            b[j] = b[j] + 2.0;
            c[j] = a[j] + b[j];
        }
    }
```

I know that openMP treats each iteration of a loop as independent of other iterations. I assume this causes e.g. iteration i=5 on thread 1 to write into a[j] of iteration i=9 of another thread, causing the difference. Is this correct? Can this be avoided, using the means of openMP?

Comment: If you parallelize the outer loop, there are race conditions (different threads reads/writes the same element of an array). To avoid race conditions use atomic operations or parallelize the inner loop only (I guess that your real code is much more complicated.)

Comment: @Laci I don't think atomic operations would be enough here: between `a[j] = a[j] + 2` and  `c[j] = a[j] + b[j]` on a thread, another thread could still update `a[j]`

Comment: Thank you, @Laci. I think you are totally right, a race condition was happening. I think I circumvented it by using `reduction` of the arrays `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: Thank you, @PierU! Do you think using `reduction` is enough here? My code survives the check now, but maybe there is something I don't see luring in the dark?

Comment: @PierU Yes, you are rigth. The same problem exist if reduction is used for `c`. `c` should be calculated in a subsequent loop.

Comment: The code immediately after the comment "Get the maximum number of threads" is unnecessary and a horrible race. I think you are looking for the function `omp_get_max_threads()` https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu112.html